# Add css class to EditorFor or validate email with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My Model is:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name="Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

When I use `EditorFor(m=>m.Email)` then the UI (JQuery Validation) validates the email address automaticaly. But I need to insert the `form-control` class to the UI control. So I changed `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor` like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But now the email validation is not working.

How can I either add the class to the `EditorFor` or add the email validation for the `TextBoxFor` (which or both is the best way?). I have other 6 properties and all are working great. All but this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use @Html.TextBoxFor

Example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Created, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or dirty way using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Email').addClass('form-control');
});
```

Comment: I didn't think about the approach of adding the form-control class when the document is ready. This work so +1 for that. But, the TextBoxForModel doesn't exists.

Comment: I quote the answare of Randolf TextBoxForModel not exist

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "form-control" })
```